# Why is my lemon juice fizzing and smelling like yeast?

Tags: lemon-juice

I have an open bottle of lemon juice that I've been keeping in the fridge. I just took it out to dress a salad and it fizzed like soda when I opened the bottle and smells like... took me a minute to place it... *yeast*. What's going on? Should I throw it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like fermentation to me.  That's what you'd expect when you're making mead or hard apple cider.

I'd personally dispose of it ... partially because I can't think of a good use for alcoholic lemon juice, but also because you don't know exactly what the bug is doing the fermentation.

Comment: Or just let it keep going and see if you can make hard-lemon-cider-vinegar!

Comment: Yeah- ok. Just throw it out.

Comment: throw it out.  There's far too much acid in the lemon juice for you to get a good fermentation.